# CAST(Column01 as NCHAR(5)) || CAST(Column02 as NCHAR(3))， but spacing display

Tags: postgresql

Column Value:
1.Column01 : '12'
2.Column02 : '34'

My SQL as follows :

```
Select CAST(Column01 as NCHAR(5)) || CAST(Column02  as NCHAR(3)) as NewColumn From Table
```

But, NewColumn value is：'1234'
I want final result should: '12   34 '

Who can tell me what? thanks!!

Comment: There is no `NCHAR` data type in Postgres. Where in the manual did you find that?

Answer (score 0):

This will pad the first column to 5 characters before concatenating it with the second column:

```
Select RPAD(Column01, 5, ' ') || Column02 as NewColumn From Table
```

Comment: Thank you, but,  I Before try your method , i want get different method.

Comment: Do you need Column01 to take up exactly 5 characters?

Comment: Yes, I want NewColumn.length=8

Comment: Updated. I'm going from memory, posting from my phone

Comment: I use other method solve it, howerver, Thanks Your help!